# How do i open PDFs with iBooks on iOS using Appcelerator ?

Tags: ios, appcelerator, ibooks

I am trying to open pdfs in my application using ibooks but i could not find any solution for this. I am using Appcelerator for this. Please share code with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the DocumentViewear (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.DocumentViewer)
or a Webview to display a PDF.
When you have opened the PDF in the DocumentViewer the user can decide 
With the action button to open the PDF in the reader he wants.

To open other apps you you have to use URL schemes 
(http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#iBooks):

```
Titanium.Platform.openURL('ibooks://');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Could you please tell me what URL should i provide for the pdf ? For instance, Titanium.Platform.openURL('ibooks://' + PDFURL)